# What are the rules for ain mukdam umeuchar?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, time, pentateuch-chumash

Sometimes we say that things in the Torah are not in chronological order. What are the parameters for this? do you need to have a mesorah (particular tradition) for this? Is there a list of all 'officially non-chronological events' that are agreed upon by all?

Comment: upupetc., welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for this interesting question! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: See this interactive shiur, that breaks down Rashi and Ramban's views on this in Sefer Shemot: http://www.tanach.org/shmot/truma/trumas1.htm

Comment: and here: http://www.vbm-torah.org/shavuot/yitro.htm

Comment: It´s too confused, who said that first?

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, no, there is no "official" list. See [this short essay](http://www.etzion.org.il/vbm/archive/1-parsha/20vayak.rtf) on the topic.

Basically, it seems  that Rashi and Ramban disagree as to how to apply this rule (Rashi considers it a blanket rule which can be applied wherever it makes sense, and Ramban considers it a tool for last resort; incidentally, this is the reverse of what I thought their Shittoth were, but I defer to R' Leibtag), and they don't necessarily agree on *when* to apply it, either.

Comment: Also (perhaps surprisingly), Ibn Ezra sides with Rashi on this one. [If I have time later, maybe I'll write a more detailed answer.]

Comment: And, on the subject, Abarbanel follows Ramban. He quotes a very interesting ibn Ezra on this parshah (Korach) and then knocks it out because it follows ein mukdam umeuchar batorah. (He does offer a similar explanation, though.)

Comment: @ba, Abarbanel does **not** follow Ramban. In general, Abarbanel believes that the Torah is *in chronological order* (within reason, of course).

Comment: That's what Ramban says, too.

Comment: @jake: "Ain mukdam u'meuchar" is a statement in the Talmud, so none of the commentaries disagree with it. The question is how liberally it can be applied. I once heard a shiur that contrasted Rashi and the Ramban's view to the whole Sefer Shemot, and it turned out according to Ramban only two verses were out of order (as opposed to Rashi who says the whole Sefer pretty much jumps around). It's fascinating because this causes a huge divergence in the story according each of the commentaries.

Comment: @jake: The Shiur is from Rabbi Paltiel. http://www.insidechassidus.org/winter/219-parshas-yisro/1081-parsha-classes-yisro.html - He gives two shiurim, one where he goes through the whole sefer Shemot according to Rashi, the other according to the Ramban.

Comment: @Menachem, `"Ain mukdam u'meuchar" is a statement in the Talmud, so none of the commentaries disagree with it.` This is false. Since when do commentaries never disagree with anything written in the Talmud? Rashi and Ramban, as you and SethJ already noted, do agree with this statement, but that does not mean that *everybody* does.

Comment: @jale: it probably would have been more correct to say, "Ain mukdam u'meuchar" is a statement in the Talmud, ***and*** none of the commentaries disagree with it. - Are you aware of any commentaries that disagree with the statement.

Comment: @Menachem, As I've already noted, `In general, Abarbanel believes that the Torah is in chronological order (within reason, of course).`

Comment: @jake: "within reason", means there are some places where he says that it is out of order. Why? Ain Mukdam etc. (Which, as pointed out above, is what the Ramban holds)

Comment: @Menachem, According to Abarbanel, the Torah is written as a narrative from a historical perspective. Therefore, just as a historical piece of literature should be in chronological order, the Torah is in chronological order. Period. However, there are circumstances where even a history book would present things *seemingly* out of order to make them more understandable to the reader. For example, to present a narrative in the general sense and then present the details of a particular part of the above narrative (e.g. Bereshis 1-2). [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] Another example: to give the details of how a particular story line finishes even if it happened much later relative to the timeline at hand (e.g. Shemos 18:27). Another example: To give background information relevant to the story at hand even if the information happened much earlier (e.g. Bamidbar 9:1). This, for Abarbanel, is not a breach of chronological ordering and it's not even considered an invocation of "ein mukdam etc."

Comment: @seth: I think this is the same article in english: http://www.vbm-torah.org/shavuot/yitro.htm , is that the case?

Comment: @jake: Perhaps it is just semantics, but it sounds like you're saying that according to the Abarbanel, the Torah is generally written in chronological order. Sometimes however, things are placed out of order in order to clarify. It is not considered going out of order because it is there to clarify the narrative. - that sounds like "ein Mukdam u'meuchar" to me. He's not saying the Torah is just a mixture of out of order topics, but follows a narrative, which sometimes requires moving things around. - compare that with these statements from here: http://www.vbm-torah.org/shavuot/yitro.htm ....

Comment: ..."Rashi's opinion, "ein mukdam u'm'uchar", should not be understood as some 'wildcard' answer that allows one to totally disregard the order in which Chumash is written. Rashi holds that the mitzvot in Chumash are organized by TOPIC, i.e. thematically, without regard to the actual chronological order in which God gave them to Moshe Rabeinu." and "Ramban argues that until there is 'clear cut' proof otherwise, one must always assume that the even the mitzvot in Chumash are recorded in the same order as they were given."

Comment: @jake:  -- However, if you have a source where the Abarbanel says he explicitly doesn't hold of ein mukdam, I'd like to see it.

Comment: @Menachem, For starters, [here's](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14388&st=&pgnum=35) where he disagrees with Chazal to claim that the *parsha* of *pesach sheni* is in fact in its proper chronological place. (This is where Chazal "derive" the principle of ein mukdam from in the gemara.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3851/discussion-between-menachem-and-jake)